# How to lazy load component and template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading, vue-component, vue-router

I have managed to lazy load components, and I have managed to lazy load templates, but I have not managed to combine these two.

Here's how I lazy load a component:

```
// This is in my main.js
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/lazy', component: () => import('./lazy.js') }
    ]
})

// And this is in lazy.js
export default {
    template: '<div>Lazy loaded component</div>'
}
```

This works just fine and I can see that `lazy.js` is not downloaded until I navigate to `/lazy`.

Here'show I lazy load a template:

```
// All of this is in my main.js
const lazyTemplate = Vue.component('lazyComponent', function(resolve) {
    fetch('./lazy.html')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(function(data) {
            resolve({
                template: data
            });
        });
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/lazy', component: lazyTemplate }
    ]
});
```

Again, this works just fine and I can see that `lazy.html` is not downloaded until I navigate to `/lazy`.

But my main problem is that I just can't figure out how to combine these to methods. How can I "natively" (without i.e. webpack) lazy load a component that lazy loads a template?

Comment: The template is bundled with the component, why do you need to combine these methods? They are effectively combined already in your first example where the template is bundled with the component hence when you lazily-load the component the template comes lazily-loaded with it as well.

Comment: Because when you have a component with several hundred lines of HTML, having all this as a string in a JS file quickly becomes unruly and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load both the template and component lazily & async and then add them together before resolving the Promise:

```
const lazyComponent = Vue.component('lazyComponent', function(resolve) {
  Promise.all([
    // fetch html template independently
    fetch('./lazy.html').then(response => response.text()),
    // fetch component js independently
    import('./lazy.js')
  ]).then(([template, module] => {
    // add template to component after both load
    let component = module.default;
    component.template = template;
    // return component with template
    resolve(component);
  }));
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/lazy', component: lazyComponent }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Unexpected token ]` on this line: `]).then(([template, component] => {`, so it seems something is wrong with `[template, component]`.

Comment: it seems the `then` can only provide one variable, which will be an array of the results of all the promises. so I can do `.then(values => { var template = value[0]; var component = value[1] }`, but the component isn't actually a component, because if I try to assign the template to it I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property template, object is not extensible`

Comment: I was using ES6 destructing assignment for `[template, component]`. You might be using a browser that doesn't support it yet, more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: `Cannot add property template, object is not extensible` hmmm, interesting. All vue components are just plain javascript objects, so as long as you're exporting your component as plain javascript from your `./lazy.js` module file I don't see why you'd be getting that error, but it would be really helpful if you could update your answer and share the code for `./lazy.js`.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 69, and that link lists Chrome 60 as the version to support everything. Seeing as it doesn't work in Chrome 69, how would you go about solving it with the array of results I'm getting in the `then(values => { })`?

Comment: Actually, the contents of `lazy.js` is already listed in the first code example (both `main.js` and `lazy.js` in the same code block)

Comment: I would try removing the `template` prop from `lazy.js` and leaving it template-less and then try running the code again. If that doesn't work I would inspect the result you're getting back from `import('./lazy.js')` to see whether or not you actually getting an object or something else. What you have currently looks like it should work though, probably just needs a little fiddling.

Comment: Removing `template` from `lazy.js` had no effect. This is how the `component` variable looks when logging it to the console: https://i.imgur.com/E0Hq4Zv.png

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense, thanks for the image. Try this: `var component = value[1].default;` That should fix it.

Comment: `.default` did the trick. I finally have a working proof of concept that I can continue to build from. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

I would try this pattern [What About Separation of Concerns](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#What-About-Separation-of-Concerns)

```html
<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
  <div>This will be pre-compiled</div>
</template>
<script src="./my-component.js"></script>
<style src="./my-component.css"></style>
```

which is a small variant on what you already do, but it means that the template does not have to be compiled in the browser (so smaller app size as the Vue compiler is not bundled).